Can't enable 'Allow sign-in requests' in outlook mobile
We are enabling MFA for all users. For some users, Outlook mobile acts as an authenticator eliminating the need to install Microsoft Authenticator. And for some users, they have to install Microsoft Authenticator.
On devices where Outlook act as an authenticator, in Outlook settings, there is this toggle that reads "Allow sign-in requests". When a user tries to turn on the toggle in Outlook Mobile settings, it says "To approve sign-ins on this device, please use the Microsoft Authenticator App". For some users, this last statement is the description of the 'Allow sign-in requests' toggle, and the toggle is greyed out.
Is there a way to make outlook authenticate sign-in requests and eliminate the need and additional app?

Outlook Mobile can indeed act as an authenticator, allowing users to approve sign-in requests via push notifications or TOTP (time-based one-time passwords). This eliminates the need for the Microsoft Authenticator app.
It looks like you want to simplify login, but multi-factor authentication is the second factor that needs to be used in addition to your password to verify your account. The default authentication method is to use the free Microsoft Authenticator application.
To set up your verification method,in addition to the admin settings, you can also add them from the Security info page, follow these steps.
Reference:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/change-your-two-step-verification-method-and-settings-c801d5ad-e0fc-4711-94d5-33ad5d4630f7


Hi Soki, if only you told me why for some users Outlook mobile works as an authenticator and for others it doesn't.

The reason why Outlook mobile works as an authenticator for some users and not for others primarily depends on a few factors: Organization's Policies, Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) Settings, User Permissions.

Do you mean the the policies in my organisation must be discriminating between users, like for some it allows Outlook mobile to do the job, and for others it doesn't, or what kind of user permissions? Can you be specific?
MFA is enforced for everyone.
